# Insert JSON responses into MySQL table with multiple responses

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a PHP file that can insert data from a JSON response into a MySQL table. The code looks like this:

```
    $jsondata = json_decode($result);
    $results = $jsondata->results;

$insert = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO History (URL, Product, Price, Status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ');

    foreach($results as $val) {


    $insert->bind_param('ssss', $val->title, $val->title, $val->price, $val->{'status/_text'});

    // //echo $val->status;
    // echo $val->{'status/_title'};

    $insert->execute();
```

Unfortunately this only works if I have 1 item coming back in my JSON response. If I have two, for all values except price, it just inserts the word ARRAY into my MySQL table.

Here is an example of a JSON response with 1 item:

```
{
   "offset": 0,
   "results": [
      {
         "status/_text": "Available",
         "status/_source": "itemID.2251694279/example333632279/",
         "status/_title": "Available",
         "title": "Product 1",
         "status": "http://www.example.comitemID.2251694279/example333632279/"
      }
   ],
   "cookies": [
      "SESSION=\""
   ],
   "GUID": "123123123",
   "GUID2": "123123123",
   "pageUrl": "http://www.example.com/279"
}
```

Here is an example of a JSON response with 2 items:

```
{
   "offset": 0,
   "results": [
      {
         "status/_text": [
            "Available",
            "Available"
         ],
         "price": "$39.29",
         "status/_source": [
            "itemID.30227999279/example333632279/",
            "itemID.30201279279/example333632279/"
         ],
         "status/_title": [
            "Available",
            "Available"
         ],
         "title": [
            "Product 1",
            "Product 2"
         ],
         "status": [
            "http://www.example.comitemID.30227999279/example333632279/",
            "http://www.example.comitemID.30201279279/example333632279/"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "cookies": [
      "SESSION=\"m\";Port=\"20\"",
      "X-AK-Origin-Instance=\"1\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"www.example.com\";Port=\"20\""
   ],
   "GUID": "123123123",
   "GUID2": "123123123",
   "pageUrl": "http://www.example.com/279"
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to start with a loop, probably easiest to sort that JSON into an array containing subarrays with easy property in them instead of having them all contained by column/property name. Then loop over it and perform your inserts, or better yet, create a single insert with multiple statements in it.

Comment: Is price always going to be a single element? Are the other fields all going to be the same length if there is more than one?

Comment: Price can be more than one- the other fields will likely be the same besides price

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is printing "Array" is because the object you you are trying to insert is a array.

You can try this to view the values:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($results->title); $i++) {
  echo $results->title[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

But I think to fix your problem, you can try changing how the server-side generates your Json object.

Comment: Hello - I cannot change the server side json since its coming from a third party app. Any recommendations on how to fit that for statement into the SQL insert? I can't seem to get data from within the json arrays

Comment: have you tried using the sample code template I have above?

try inserting the code above in your script, it should print the titles in the JSon object. If it works, try adding the variables for other variables in the Json object except for the price.

Comment: Hi Nikko - that gives me the message Notice: Trying to get property of non-object if I put it within the for each. If I put only   echo $val->title[0] . "<br/>" I do get one value back! Not sure exactly how to loop this within the foreach to get all the results though?

Comment: Hi AAA, sorry it should be $results->title[0] not $val->title[$i]